# html input type email does not work for german chars like ä ü ö

Tags: angularjs, html, email-validation

I have an angularJS application with this html:

```
  <input type="email" ng-model="model.email"
  pattern="[\u0020-\u0039\u0041-\u007E]+@@.+\..+"
  ng-class="{ invalid : formB.email.$dirty && formB.email.$invalid }" required>
```

It additionally makes sure that "test@yahoo" is not a valid email.

I want now to allow emails with ä ö ü chars so I changed it to this regex:

```
pattern="[\u0020-\u0039\u0041-\u007E\u00E4]+@@.+\..+"

ä => \u00E4
```

The email "test@gmäil.com" is still invalid, but why? I am a regex starter maybe thats the problem.

I need that workaround because  ä ö ü is not allowed on html email input using firefox for example!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for. JavaScript doesn't account for these chars you have to be more specific.

Regular chars
 [A-Za-z0-9 -_.äöüß etc]

Unicode:  You can reference them here http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

[A-Za-z0-9 -_.\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]

Comment: dont get it... but \u00E4 was correct unicde for 'ä' what does your regex in the last line mean? I see there no 'ä'

Comment: Sorry I just typed some random characters out that I saw quickly.  I hop the url I provided helped.

Comment: No that does not help, because I do not want to regard a random copy/pasted Regex, I want to know why my Regex with the '\u00E4' does not work!